# How to translate "Commodity traders" in this context?

Tags: traduction

I want to translate "Commodity traders in agriculture ... " to French, but the suggestions I found when googling it gave "négociants" which didn't seem correct to me. 
Is that the correct translation of it in this context?

Answer (score 2):

I think "Négociant" is the right word. There is no hard disctinction between "trader" and "broker" in the french language. "Négociant" actually fits both. "Speculateur" may sounds a bit pejorative, especially in France where Stock Exchange activities kind of look suspicious for people not in the know.

"Négociants en matières premières agricoles" sounds good to me.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

> *Spéculateurs<sup>1</sup> en matière premières agricoles.*

*Commodités agricoles* might to be used too in the trader's jargon:

> *Chez les professionnels, on ne parle pas de matières premières, mais de commodités, anglicisme commode.* [*Alternatives Économiques*](https://www.alternatives-economiques.fr/matieres-premieres-fonctionnent-marches-de-commodites/00030853), 2005

<sup>1</sup> <sub>***Trader*** is often used in French and might be less pejorative than *speculateur*.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

> activités de trading sur matières premières agricoles

ou plus court:

> activités de trading sur produits agricoles

Comment: Tant qu'à ne pas traduire, autant laisser *trader* qui est couramment utilisé en France.

Answer (score 1):

Comme exprimé par ailleurs les traductions possibles de *trader* sont, du plus neutre au plus péjoratif, *négociant*, *trader*, *spéculateur*. En réalité, tout dépend des conditions d'exercice de l'activité: quelqu'un qui sillonne les campagnes et les coopératives agricoles à l'époque de la moisson sera plutôt qualifié de *négociant*, alors qu'un autre derrière son ordinateur connecté à la bourse de commerce de Chicago portera mieux les termes de *trader* ou *spéculateur*.

Comment: En d'autres temps, tu en aurais oublié un de *négociant en produits agricoles* : maquignon ! Considérant son devenir, on ne peut que trouver curieux la destinée de ces mots au sens péjoratif.